# Ищу способ воспроизвести аудио файл на микрофон как в Soundpad c#

Tags: c#, .net, аудио

Ищу способ воспроизвести аудио файл на микрофон как в Soundpad

Comment: Посмотрите возможности NuGet пакета NAudio

Answer (score -1):

```
To play an audio file through the microphone in C#, you can use the WasapiOut class from the NAudio library. Here is an example of how you can use this class to play an audio file through the microphone:
 1. Install the NAudio NuGet package.
 2. Add the following using statement to your code:
using NAudio.Wave;
 3. Use the following code to play an audio file through the microphone:

    // Create a new WaveOut object
WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut();

// Create a new WasapiOut object with the device set to the default microphone
IWavePlayer wavePlayer = new WasapiOut(NAudio.CoreAudioApi.AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 100);

// Create a new AudioFileReader object and set its output to the WaveOut object
AudioFileReader audioFileReader = new AudioFileReader("AudioFile.mp3");
waveOut.Init(audioFileReader);

// Start playing the audio file through the microphone
waveOut.Play();


This code will play the audio file "AudioFile.mp3" through the default microphone. You can use the WasapiOut class to control the volume and mute the audio as well.
```

Comment: ага, в динамики выводит, а в микрофон фиг тебе